# Найти первый символ в первом максимально длинном слове с четным числом символов в строке

Tags: kotlin

Написал, программу по следующему **ТЗ**:

**Найти первый символ в первом максимально длинном слове с четным числом символов в строке. В строке указываются только слова, разделенные одним или несколькими пробелами.**

При тестовых данных:

**1234 4567 23456789**

Выводит результат:
**4**

Хотя по логике описанной в тз, должна вывести 2.
Т.К число 23456789 - первое максимально длинное слово, а так же количество символов в нем четное.

Кто подскажет в чем может быть проблема?

**UPD:
Забыл добавить, алгоритм должен быть реализован максимально оптимизированно по быстродействию т.е нельзя использовать такие функции как(split,filter и т.д)
Так же нельзя использовать списки.**

```
fun main()
{
    var s = readLine();
    var word = "";
    var max = 0;
    var s2 = "";
    if(s!=null)
    {
        for(c in s)
        {
            s2+=c;
            println(s2);
            if(c.toInt() == 32)
            {
                var b = s2.length;
                var s3 = s2;
                s2="";
                if((b-1 > max) && ((b-1) % 2 == 0))
                {
                    max = b-1;
                    word = s3;
                    //println(word);
                    //println(max);
                }

            }
        }
        
        if(word != "")
        {
            println(word[0]);
        }
        else
        {
            println("Слов кратных двум не было.")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: а требование  называть переменные как s3 и без функций одним проходом -- это тоже часть ТЗ ...

Comment: а что делать, если слов с четным количеством букв нет?

Comment: @Эникейщик Если слов с четным количеством букв нет, не так важно. 
Можно ничего не выводить, можно вывести (таких слов нет), но с этим я сам могу разобраться)

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov требования к названиям переменным не было не каких. Так же по поводу функций, можно было вынести в отдельные блоки, но это не обязательно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Данный код, вроде бы, решает Вашу задачу:

```
    private val Int.isEven //Extension свойство для Int, проверяет четность числа через битовое И
        get() = and(1) != 1

    private fun getFirstLetterOfBiggestWordWithEvenLettersNumber(text: String): Char {
        var length = 0 // Сколько букв в слове, по которому идём сейчас
        var maxLength = 0 // Насколько длинным было самое длинное слово из пройденных раньше (вообще, учитываться будут только слова с четным числом букв)
        var lastWordBegin = '-' // С какой буквы началось слово, по которому бежим сейчас
        var result = '-' // Здесь храним ответ

        for (letter in text) { // Для каждой буквы текста
            if (letter == ' ') { // Если это пробел

                if (length.isEven && length > maxLength) { // Если в слове было четное число букв и оно самое длинное из найденных
                    maxLength = length // Запоминаем длину
                    result = lastWordBegin // Запоминаем первую букву закончившегося слова как ответ
                }

                length = 0 // Слово кончилось
                continue // Переходим к следующей букве
            }

            if (length == 0) lastWordBegin = letter // Запоминаем первую букву нового слова

            length++ // Длина текущего слова увеличилась на 1
        }

        if (length.isEven && length > maxLength) result = lastWordBegin // В конце текста не будет пробела, так что проверим последнее слово

        return result
    }
```

Ну и комментарий по поводу Вашего стиля кода. Старайтесь давать говорящие имена всем функциям, методам, переменным и классам, иначе даже после перерыва в виде выходных Вам самому будет очень сложно разобраться в своем коде. Ну и когда работать пойдете - Вас убьют за некрасивые имена переменных куда скорее, чем за алгоритмы:)

P.s. Хорошая проверка - если Вы назвали что-то именем короче 8 символов, то это уже повод задуматься. (не относится к итераторам в циклах (i,j) и координатам (x,y,z) из математики)

Comment: Спасибо, ваш ответ помог мне для решения задачи, интерпритировал ваш код так понимаю написанный на C# в код на Kotlin

Comment: @roxyashechka нет, это чистейший Kotlin

Comment: ааа, точно, из-за модификаторов доступов не совсем понял, что это котлин т.к до этого не дашел, на с# они похожим образом выглядели.

Comment: @Alex_Skvotsov а вы случайно не знаете как реализовать программу(не эту) через хвостовую рекурсию tailrec

Comment: Как простейший пример - `tailrec fun divideByTenUntilZero(num: Int): Int = if (num < 10) num else divideByTenUntilZero(num)`. По сути, ключевое слово tailrec нужно не Вам, а компилятору. Главное - функция должна быть рекурсивной и рекурсивный вызов должен быть в хвосте функции

Comment: А допустим программа, где на вход идет строка и нужно посчитать сумму цифр кратных трем

Comment: @roxyashechka Строка из цифр? Если так, то параметры функции - текущая сумма и оставшаяся строка. При вызове функции проверяем длину строки. Если строка пуста - возвращаем сумму, полученную как параметр. Если строка содержит цифры, то вызываем себя же с параметрами `наша строка без первого символа` и `сумма из параметра плюс (Если первая цифра кратна 3 - эта цифра, иначе 0)` Изначально вызываем функцию с суммой равной 0

Comment: При проверке, if(str.length == 0) sum -  Replace size zero chek with 'isEmpty'

Comment: Могу ещё одну задачу создать, где вы на неё сможете ответить полноценно?
private tailrec fun sumDigits(sum:Int,str:String):Int = if(str.length == 0) sum else if()
Что нужно писать в If после else

Comment: задача - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1175833

Comment: @roxyashechka "Replace size zero chek with 'isEmpty'"  - это рекомендация, а не ошибка. Вместо `str.length == 0` можно писать `str.isEmpty()`

Comment: У меня получилось как то так https://gist.github.com/roxyash/9c81ac58a54b17e12cae5a6f7645b264, но чего то не хватает

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112789/discussion-between-alex-skvortsov-and-roxyashechka).

Answer (score 2):

4 и 2 - неверные ответы. Верный ответ - 1.

По условию, во-первых, количество символов в слове должно брать четным. А в `2345678` нечетное количество. А во-вторых, ищется первый символ из ***первого*** найденного слова, удовлетворяющего условиям. И это слово `1234`.

*PS. В котлине у строк есть метод split(), который сразу разделит строку по словам.*

Comment: Поправил вопрос, нужно сделать скрипт максимально оптимизированный скрипт по быстродействию, т.е без использования функций(split,filter и т.д)

Answer (score 1):

```
val input = "1234 4567 2345678"
val output = input.split(" ")
        .filter { word -> word.length > 0 && word.length % 2 == 0 }
        .maxBy { word -> word.length } !![0]
println(output)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: @Sergei Kirjanov Поправил вопрос, нужно сделать  максимально оптимизированный скрипт по быстродействию, т.е без использования функций(split,filter и т.д)

Comment: @roxyashechka Не факт, что реализация на примитивных операциях будет быстрее - встроенные функции могут быть неплохо оптимизированы

Comment: @MBo это не моя инициатива, а преподавателя.

Answer (score 1):

Маленькая машина состояний.
Вначале состояние 0.
MaxLen = 0
Идёте по строке.

Встретили не пробел в состоянии 0 - изменили состояние на 1, запомнили символ, запомнили позицию.

Встретили пробел в состоянии 1 - изменили состояние на 0, вычислили разность с запомненной позицией, если она чётная и больше MaxLen - скопировали запомненный ранее символ в результат.
То же самое - при достижении конца строки.

В остальных случаях ничего не делается.